# How can I make tags in tagsets visible to users who want to tag contacts

Tags: tags

When I have a group of tags in a tagset, I notice that when I'm trying to add tags to a contact I can't see the list of tags (as I would if it was a standard CiviCRM multi-select field).

Instead all I have is the option of keying characters in and seeing possible matches. I guess that approach is OK if all my users know the tags well, but for a new user who doesn't know the tags it's a bit daft, and I'll end up having to produce a cheat sheet with all the tags on it.

Is there a reason why these tagset fields are different from conventional multi-select fields? Is there a simple way to change them so that the tags do appear in a drop-down as well as responding to keyed characters?

I'm working with CiviCRM 4.7.24 and Wordpress 4.8.2, and I see the same behaviour regardless of whether I add tags from the contact summary screen or by editing the contact record.

Comment: What version of Civi and a CMS are you running? Also, are you adding tags from the contact summary/record or from the edit screen?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to provide the detail that you've requested. Essentially no difference in behaviour regardless of whether I edit the contact record or just click on Tags from the summary screen.

Comment: Could it be that the user doesn't have permission to see the tags?

Comment: In this instance the 'user' is me, and I have full admin access. I was also able to replicate on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. I regard this as a bug and will log an issue accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

By design, tagsets are an auto complete drop down.
However, there is one thing we could do to improve the usability: make the list open immediately and show the complete list of tags.
I don't really see a downside to that change so I'll make a PR and see if anyone objects.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12248

UPDATE: The feature has been accepted and will be released with CiviCRM 5.3.0.

[image]

Comment: I think this approach greatly improves the utility of tagsets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer - but a follow up, I wanted to include an image. I checked out the demo and was wondering if I missed what you referred to originally. On the tags tab, I see the attached. Where the list is checkable list. Is this not what you are seeing, perhaps I misunderstood.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I see this too. These visible tags are not in a tagset. Only tags in a tagset get hidden from the user.